# Ассемблер и массивы

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте. Собственно есть вопрос. Как можно вычислить сумму элементов нашего массива, у которого индексы совпадают со значениями нашего массива. Инициализацию массива я могу сделать, а как реализовать проверку и вычисление, ассемблер видел пару раз.

Comment: Покажите как именно выглядит массив.

Comment: Если это то, о чём я думаю, то задача сводится к нахождению суммы целых чисел от 0 до `длина_массива`. А в этом случае сам массив нам и не нужен.

Comment: IMHO, if (a[i] == i) {sum += i;}

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, сравните 2 формулировки: "*сумма элементов массива, **у которого** индексы совпадают со значениями элементов*" и "*сумма элементов массива, **индексы которых** совпадают со значениями элементов*". IMHO, в вопросе озвучен первый вариант, у вас в коде - второй :)

Comment: Согласен, есть разница :-) В таком случае я бы уточнил у препода какой именно вариант. Если первый вариант - там что-то типа такого будет: add eax, ecx; dec ecx; jnz loop

Comment: Если известно количество элементов, тогда можно без каких либо циклов найти через сумму арифметической прогрессии

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Размышления, пожалуй, вынесу в ответ. Дело в том, что в такой формулировке:

> Найти сумму элементов массива, значения которого совпадают с
>   индексами.

задача решается без массива в принципе.Она просто сводится к нахождению суммы целых чисел от нуля до **длина_массива** и сам массив нам не нужен вообще. Очевидный, и часто приходящий в голову вариант - цикл:

```
    xor eax, eax
    xor edx, edx
    mov ecx, array_size-1 ; нужно пояснять -1?
sum1:
    add eax, ecx
    adc edx, 0
    loop sum1
    ; результат в eax:edx
```

Но можно обойтись и без циклов, как предложил @Ni55aN, посчитать сумму арифметической прогрессии:

[image: asum]

Важно! Мы должны быть уверены, что при вычислении числителя получим *чётное* число, иначе такой подход не сработает. В этом задании так и есть, но если применять этот подход для других прогрессий - могут быть варианты:

```
mov edx, array_size    
; значение последнего элемента массива равно
; его размеру-1 (по условию: первый элемент - 0,
; второй - 1, третий - 2, и т.д.)
; а первый добавлять не надо, он и так 0
mov eax, array_size-1  
mul edx
sar edx, 1
rcr eax, 1
; результат в eax:edx
```

Ну а если формулировка задания всё-таки другая, например:

> Найти сумму элементов массива, значения в котором совпадают с
>   индексами

(разница в нескольких буквах, но она существенна), то всё просто: проходимся по массиву, сравниваем значение элемента с его индексом, совпало - накапливаем сумму.

Ну и напоследок - проверка всех трёх вариантов:

```
; ----------------------------------
section .data
array       dd  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
asize equ   ($ - array)/4

s1          db  'Direct array scanning:  %llu', 0Ah, 0
s2          db  'With cycle:             %llu', 0Ah, 0
s3          db  'Arithmetic progression: %llu', 0Ah, 0
; ----------------------------------
section .text
extern printf
global main
; ----------------------------------
main:
; полный проход по массиву:
    cld
    mov esi, array
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor edx, edx
sum1:
    lodsd
    add ebx, eax
    adc edx, 0
sum2:
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, asize
    jne sum1

    push edx
    push ebx
    push s1
    call printf
    add esp, 12

; считаем сумму в цикле:
    xor eax, eax
    xor edx, edx
    mov ecx, asize-1
sum3:
    add eax, ecx
    adc edx, 0
    loop sum3

    push edx
    push eax
    push s2
    call printf
    add esp, 12

; считаем сумму прогрессии:
    mov edx, asize
    ;mov eax, [array+((asize-1)*4)]
    mov eax, asize-1
    mul edx
    sar edx, 1
    rcr eax, 1

    push edx
    push eax
    push s3
    call printf
    add esp, 12

    ret   
; ----------------------------------
```

Comment: в этой формуле числитель ВСЕГДА четный (либо в скобках, либо n - четные)

Comment: В этой - да, я так, на будущее :)